# Multi stage probability events

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Three students are selected at random from a group of $6$ boys and $4$ girls. How many combinations are possible that contain exactly $2$ boys? The answer is $120$.

I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: A common technique would be to start by counting the number of ways to choose the two boys. In how many ways can this happen? After you've chosen the two boys, what else needs to be decided?

Answer (score 3):

The answer isn't 120, it's 60. If you choose three students and require there be exactly 2 boys, then there is exactly 1 girl. Thus, we need to choose 2 boys out of the 6, and 1 girl out of the 4. There are $$\binom{6}{2} = 15$$ ways to pick 2 boys out of 6. Multiply this by the 4 choices for a girl and you get $$15 \times 4 = 60$$.